# SQL Server: Filter out duplicate value from a specific column of the output

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have the following query which runs against a View Table:

```
USE MyDatabase
SELECT a.ResaId, a.MTH, a.Market, SUM(a.Guest) AS 'Pax'
FROM RESLIST a
GROUP BY a.ResaId, a.MTH, a.Market
```

The Output (extract) is as follows:

```
ResaId      MTH     Market    Pax
  252     Jan-15    France     3
  346     FEB-15    UK         2
  346     MAR-15    UK         2
  112     MAR-15    GERMANY    4
  587     JUL-15    Italy      3
  587     AUG-15    Italy      3
```

I need my output to exclude those 2 duplicate ResaID: 346 and 587. So, output needs to be as follows:

```
ResaId      MTH     Market    Pax
  252     Jan-15    France     3
  346     FEB-15    UK         2
  112     MAR-15    GERMANY    4
  587     JUL-15    Italy      3
```

The SELECT DISTINCT syntax is not working. I guess it is because the values in the entire ROWS are not duplicates.

I just need to eliminate the SECOND ROW which has the duplicate ResaID.

How do I write the relevant syntax to my existing query to achieve this?

Comment: use distinct on the column you want inside the select statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function like

```
SELECT 
    ResaId,
    MTH,
    Market,
    Pax
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         a.ResaId, a.MTH, a.Market, SUM(a.Guest) AS 'Pax',
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.ResaId ORDER BY a.ResaId) AS rn
     FROM 
         RESLIST a
     GROUP BY 
         a.ResaId, a.MTH, a.Market) xx
WHERE 
    rn = 1;
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what I needed!